# Mongoose Schema for geoJson coordinates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I tried to create a schema for [geojson](http://geojson.org/) but have had some problems with syntax  for coordinates.

Here's my current code:

```
var DataSchema = new Schema({
  properties: {
    title:       { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    date:        { type:Date, default:Date.now }
  },
  geometry: {
       coordinates: []
  }
});
```

I tried using `[]` (empty array), it creates `''` and `[Number,Number]` but it doesn't work.

My question is: how do I have to construct my schema so as result I will get

```
coordinates: [ 3.43434343, 5.543434343 ]
```

without quotation marks, is this possible?

Express Route

```
   app.post('/mountain_rescue',  function (req, res){

      new rescueData({properties:{title: req.body.title, description:  req.body.description},geometry:{
     coordinates:req.body.coordinates}}).save(function (e, result) {
             console.log(result);
         });
     res.redirect('/mountain_rescue');
  });
```

View

```
<div id="AddingPanel">
  <form method="post" action="mountain_rescue" >
      Title:<input type="text" name="title">
      Description:<textarea type="text" name="description"></textarea>
      Coordinates:<input type="text" name="coordinates">
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: You take the example of "Point" but you might want to handle various types of features, with different types of coordinates (arrays for Point, arrays of arrays for LineString, and arrays of arrays of arrays for Polygon, MultiLineString)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this;

```
var DataSchema = new Schema({
  properties: {
    title:       { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    date:        { type:Date, default:Date.now }
  },
  geometry: {
    coordinates: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'}
  }
});
```

Here is your update route handler, it converts coordinates string to number array;

```
app.post('/mountain_rescue',  function (req, res) {
  new rescueData({
    properties: {
      title: req.body.title, description: req.body.description
    },
    geometry: {
      coordinates:req.body.coordinates.split(',').map(Number)
    }
  }).save(function (e, result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
  res.redirect('/mountain_rescue');
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but it works only when i type one number: 3.4343 else when typing two 3.43, 4.343 it is undefined.

Comment: make sure req.body.coordinates is array of two numbers, which in your case is not. its just a comma separated string e.g  3.43, 4.343

Comment: i don't get it, should i type [3.43, 4.3343] into input?

Comment: No, that would still be a string when it gets to server, try something like; req.body.coordinates.split(',').map(Number) which will return an array of numbers

Comment: I did as you say but without .map(Number) but still works great, it is a big deal i should use .map(Number) ?

Comment: No, its just to make sure strings are converted to number, which, as it seems, is being done by driver anyway

Comment: one more question. after i removed index: '2dsphere ' everything works just fine too?

Comment: That is required if later-on you wanted to perform geospatial queries. not required if you don't need to do that

Answer (score 16):

A GeoJSON field has to be included a geometry type as a string. So a GeoJSON field must be defined like the following;

```
geometry: { type: { type: String }, coordinates: [Number] }
```

or if you want to define a default value you might use the below line;

```
geometry: { type: { type: String, default:'Point' }, coordinates: [Number] }
```

Good luck..

Comment: Works only with Point, not any GeoJSON field

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var DataSchema = new Schema({
  properties: {
    title:       { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    date:        { type:Date, default:Date.now }
  },
  geometry: {
       coordinates: {type: Array, required: true}
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried it before, in mognodb result is like this "coordinates":["1.434343, 4.21322"], and with these quotation marks is not readable as geojson, i checked on my previous project. But i am curious why if it is an array, mongo is putting quotation marks?