# Mongoose GeoJSON throws "MongoError: Can't extract geo keys" when using middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I'm using Mongoose in my NodeJS project, and I have a GeoJSON object in a subdocument array:

**ParentSchema.js**

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import ChildeSchema from '[path]/ChildSchema.js';

const ParentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  children: [ChildSchema],
  ...
});
```

**ChildSchema.js**

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import geocoder from '[path]/geocoder.js'; // where I initialize the geocoder

const ChildSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  location: {    
    // GeoJSON
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      default: 'Point'
    },
    // first enter longitude, then latitude
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number]
    //index: '2dsphere'  <-- committed out, also tried with the index
    }
  },
  ...
});

// middleware goes here

export default ChildSchema;
```

I added a middleware in the `ChildSchema` that gets location information using `geocoder` that works with *mapquest*.

**Middleware (in ChildSchema.js):**

```js
ChildScheme.pre('save', async function (next) {

  const geoDetails = await geocoder.geocode(this.fullAddress); // works fine, I'm getting the location

  // values are legal
  const latitude = geoDetails[0].latitude;
  const longitude = geoDetails[0].longitude;

  this.location = {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [longitude, latitude] 
    };

  next();
}
```

When I try creating a new Parent document (using POST with application/json Content-Type) I'm getting the following error:

> MongoError: Can't extract geo keys: *{the_parent_document}* geo element must be an array or object: type: \"Point\"

I tried applying the answers I found in the following questions but it didn't help:
[mongoose geojson in schema, “Can't extract geo keys” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023793/mongoose-geojson-in-schema-cant-extract-geo-keys-error)
[MongoError: Can't extract geo keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096141/mongoerror-cant-extract-geo-keys)
[Mongoose Schema for geoJson coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749471/mongoose-schema-for-geojson-coordinates)
[How does one represent MongoDB GeoJSON fields in a Mongoose Schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556624/how-does-one-represent-mongodb-geojson-fields-in-a-mongoose-schema)
[Can't extract geo keys, unknown GeoJSON type: { coordinates: [ 13.42493130000003, 52.50074619999999 ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398459/cant-extract-geo-keys-unknown-geojson-type-coordinates-13-42493130000003)

What am I missing? Thank you for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Changed the name of the key to something else than `location` and it worked...